# Converting std::wsting to char* with wcstombs_s

Tags: c++, string, c++11, wstring

I have input strings that contain only digits (just the plain Latin ones, 0-9, so for example "0123"), stored as std::wstring, and I need each as a char*. What's the best way for me to do this? This is my initial approach:

```
void type::convertWStringToCharPtr(_In_ std::wstring input, _Out_ char * outputString)
{
    outputString = new char[outputSize];
    size_t charsConverted = 0;
    const wchar_t * inputW = input.c_str();
    wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, outputString, sizeof(outputString), inputW, input.length());
}
```

EDIT: The code below works. Thanks all!

```
void type::convertWStringToCharPtr(_In_ std::wstring input, _Out_ char * outputString)
{
    size_t outputSize = input.length() + 1; // +1 for null terminator
    outputString = new char[outputSize];
    size_t charsConverted = 0;
    const wchar_t * inputW = input.c_str();
    wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, outputString, outputSize, inputW, input.length());
}
```

Comment: sizeof(outputstring) doesnt do what u think it does; it tells you how big the pointer is

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code. I thought that wcstombs_s wanted the size of the pointer for some reason.

Comment: And it is still not working?

Comment: It is now. I've updated the post with the working code. Thank you!

Comment: Please please please use `unique_ptr<char[]>` rather than declaring a raw pointer here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory for your buffer:

```
char * outputString = new char[input.length()];
```

Should be

```
char * outputString = new char[input.length() + 1];
```

because of terminating NUL-character.

Oh, and also, as per [pm100](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173397/pm100)'s comment: `sizeof(outputString)` is giving you the size of the pointer. You should use `input.length() + 1`, as that is the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of errors in your code. First, you're not allocating enough space in your destination buffer for the NULL character. You must allocate at least `input.length() + 1` chars for the function to succeed.

Second, you're not passing in the correct size of the output buffer to the function. `sizeof(outputString)` returns the size of `outputString` itself, a `char *`, and not the number of bytes pointed to by that pointer.

So your function should look like this:

```
void CoverageTileManager::convertWStringToCharPtr(_In_ std::wstring input, _Out_ char * outputString)
{
    size_t outputSize = input.length() + 1;
    outputString = new char[outputSize];
    size_t charsConverted = 0;
    wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, outputString, outputSize, input.c_str(), input.length());
    // TODO verify charsConverted = outputSize
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++ I would never use pure pointers: use `vector` if a char array needed in heap! Do you want to copy the source string? If not, const reference should be used for `input`. `wcstombs_s` is used only in Windows, so why doesn't use simply [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Was the conversion success? Return value.

```
bool CoverageTileManager::convertWStringToCharPtr(const std::wstring& input, std::vector<char>& outputString )
{
    if ( input.empty() ) {
       return false;
    }
    int size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,input.c_str(),input.size(),NULL,0,NULL,NULL);
    if ( size <= 0 ) {
      return false;
    }
    outputString.resize(size+1);
    if ( WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,input.c_str(),input.size(),&outputString[0],size,NULL,NULL) <= 0 ) {
       outputString.clear();
       return false;
    }
    outputString[size] = '\0';
    return true;
}
```

Use vector to external C++ lib:

```
extern void call( const char*, size_t);
std::vector<char> buffer;
std::wstring input;
...
if ( convertWStringToCharPtr(input,buffer) ) {
    call(&buffer[0],buffer.size());
}
```

Comment: I have no choice about the char* type - it's required by an external library that I'm stuck with. If I had my way it would just take a std::wstring, a perfectly capable type for the work it's doing, and no conversion would be necessary.

Comment: @fatcat1111: I cannot believe this design: get a `wstring` and use C style string as a target. Strange. Poor you! :)

Comment: @fatcat1111: vector could be used external for C or C++ functions.